# How to create a table with dynamic columns amount using JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have troubles with understanding how to create a table with dynamic amount of columns using *JasperReports* and *iReport*.
All solutions I have found using google lead me to nowhere.

Specific of my situation is that I have no opportunity to change a method that returns me a data. it returns it in a following form:
List of headers (length n)
List of objects, each of them contains data for a single row in a form of a List (length n)

The ideal solution for me would be some kind of a for loop that goes through every element in the row and adds a column for it.

Is such thing possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can use [*JasperReports API*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/) or [*DynamicJasper API*](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/), for example

Comment: Could you possibly point me to some good examples of usage?